# Google Services Framework repeated pop up and how to stop it?

Tags: google-play-services

So my LG Android lite keeps appearing a pop up that says "Unfortunately, Google Services Framework has stopped". I have checked here for solutions but my device has one more issue, anytime I open any of my apps it crashes and says it also has stopped working. This means I cannot even open my settings to uninstall anything or force stop anything. Looking for help as I can't use my phone at all!!!

Comment: This is an older device? You may need to see if you can manually update the Google apps. If it is older, you will do yourself a favor by getting a new device. I can't explain any further as I suspect it might get too complicated for you.